# Tree shaking with lodash-es

Tags: webpack, lodash, tree-shaking

I'm trying to configure tree shaking for our bundles using webpack. I'm looking to replace `lodash` with `lodash-es`. I know there are webpack plugins that will enable lodash tree-shaking but I'm looking to go straight to `lodash-es` cause our webpack configuration is a little complex.

When I look at the bundle size, I notice that the bundle is a lot smaller when I import using absolute path like: `import merge from 'lodash-es/merge'` as opposed to using a named import like: `import { merge } from 'lodash-es'`.

Is this an expected behaviour or is this more indicative of tree-shaking not being configured properly?

Answer (score 1):

This should be tree shaken correctly:

- `lodash-es/package.json` sets `sideEffects: false`, at least in the current version

Other things you can check:

- if you have optimizations on - may it's a development build, and the tree shaking is not done
- if you have `babel` or some other tool turning your es-module into something that doesn't work with treeshaking.